# Baton XML to Vantage XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to translate this section of XML into a Vantage XSLT. I'm having difficulty returning the value of "Sample Aspect Ratio". Any assistance would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

XML is as follows:

```
 <info>
      <field name="Sample Aspect Ratio" timecode="00:59:59:000" value="1:1" />
 </info>
```

My XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http//www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:default="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>  





    <xsl:template match="/">
        <soa:Label xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core" identifier="fb12e158-bf94-423f-8f9a-ef315f352d1a" name="Baton" description="Contains the results of the Baton analysis" leftaligncheckboxes="false" instance="a5c1a52c-42ad-4499-a3ec-742171451945" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" menuname="" itemmode="closed">
            <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="065bb619-d0ab-4a69-98d2-9c6a45224db0" bindable="True" name="Sample Aspect Ratio" enabled="true" enabledinvariants="true" disableable="false" browsable="true" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">     
                <xsl:value-of select="/info/field[@name='Sample Aspect Ratio']/@value"/>
                <soa:Default></soa:Default>
                <soa:Option></soa:Option>
            </soa:Parameter>
        </soa:Label>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' and local-name()='p']">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What difficulty are you having? The transform you present, applied to the input you provided, emits an `<soa:Label>` with a `<soa:Parameter>` child having content "1.1", as drawn from the `<field>` element in the input document.  How is that different from what you're after?

Comment: In addition, your 2nd template does not do anything.